Problem with POCO HTTPS request on Android app
I'm trying to use POCO https requests on Android app. I'm using poco 1.10.1 (I built poco with BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL) and my setup for SSL looks like this:
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert = new Poco::Net::ConsoleCertificateHandler(false);
SSLContext = new Context(Context::TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE, "", Context:: VERIFY_STRICT, 9, true, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(0, ptrCert, SSLContext);

after https request I'm still getting error error: SSL Exception: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED, code: 0, what: SSL Exception
Anyone has idea what else should be configured to make it work ?
